# Using android data to stitch multiple images

Tags: opencv, android-camera, camera-calibration, image-stitching

I am using gyroscope data from android phone to stitch two images. The image are placed as if they are flipped.
rotation matrix of camera from gyroscope-

```
            double thetaOverTwo = gyroscopeRotationVelocity * dT / 2.0f;
            double sinThetaOverTwo = Math.sin(thetaOverTwo);
            double cosThetaOverTwo = Math.cos(thetaOverTwo);

            deltaQuaternion.setY((float) (sinThetaOverTwo * axisX));
            deltaQuaternion.setX(-(float) (sinThetaOverTwo * axisY));
            deltaQuaternion.setZ((float) (sinThetaOverTwo * axisZ));
            deltaQuaternion.setW(-(float) cosThetaOverTwo); 


    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, (-(float) (2.0f * Math.acos(q.getW()) * 180.0f / Math.PI)), q.getX(), q.getY(), q.getZ());
```

Note: Above set of equation is used because android phone is always used in landscape mode.
[image: wrong output, without flipping image]
Each time I click an image, rotation matrix calculated from above code is pushed to rot_mat vector;
Now I am using the same matrix as camera rotation matrix, but the output is as if images are flipped.

```
Mat ref_matg = rot_mat[mid]; // mid is index of reference image
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_images; ++i){

    Mat R = rot_mat[i]*ref_matg.inv();
    R.convertTo(R, CV_32F);
    cameras[i].R = R;
    cameras[i].focal = focal;
    cameras[i].ppx = ppx;
    cameras[i].ppy = ppy;
    cameras[i].aspect = aspect;

}
```

However if I use the same code, by initially flipping all the images, the output is correct. 
[image: correct output, images are flipped in this case, the rotation matrix is applied]Can anyone give me reason behind this.

Comment: I found one solution to include a transformation matrix while calculating homography matrix. H = trans.inv() * k * rot * k.inv() *trans {k cameras intrinsic matrix, trans = [-1, 0, img.witdh, 0,1, 0,  0, 0 , 1], rot - android data }, buts still unable to find the reason